# Add user which has free/busy access to all calendars on Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, user-permissions

I've been given a challenge in relation to an ongoing IP telephony project at my workplace. The coming system features a client installed on every user's computer from where they can do lookups on colleague's information, their call history and whatnot.

For this system to work, they've asked for an Exchange 2010 user which is to be used by this system to retreive information about all users - it's this information which is then accessed by these fancy-pancy clients on the user's computers. My initial problem with this, as the topic states, is regarding calendars. I can't seem to find any information about an easy way to have a single user which has access to all users' calendars by default.

I've been able to dig up some information on how to grant calendar read access to *n* users on a single calendar using some 3rd party tools such as PFDavAdmin. First of all, I'm looking for a way to grant access for a single user to *n* calendars. Second, I'm hoping that this can, somehow, be done through the standard management console/shell.

For now, the easist solution which pops into my mind is doing this via a PowerShell script - simply iterate through all calendars and grants access to this specific system user. On the other hand, this has some obvious downsides such as needing to make this a scheduled task in order for these rights to be applied to new users and such which is why I'm hoping there is a better way of doing this :)

*Thank you for your time

Christian*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 Availability service makes free/busy information available to Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 and Outlook Web App clients. The Availability service improves information workers' calendaring and meeting scheduling experience by providing secure, consistent, and up-to-date free/busy information. By default, this service is installed with Exchange 2010.

Outlook 2007 and Outlook Web App use the Availability service to perform the following tasks:

- Retrieve current free/busy
  information for Exchange 2010
  mailboxes
- Retrieve current free/busy
  information from other Exchange 2010
  organizations
- Retrieve published free/busy
  information from public folders for
  mailboxes on servers that have
  versions of Exchange earlier than
  Exchange 2010
- View attendee working hours
- Show meeting time suggestions

You need to be assigned permissions before you can perform this procedure. To see what permissions you need, see the "Availability Service Permissions" entries in the [Client Access Permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638131.aspx)  topic. This example sets the organization-wide account on the availability configuration object to configure the access level for free/busy information in the target forest.

```
Set-AvailabilityConfig -OrgWideAccount "Domain\User"
```

This example adds the Availability address space configuration object for the source forest.

```
$a = get-credential  (Enter the credentials for organization-wide user in Contoso.com domain)
Add-AvailabilityAddressspace -Forestname Contoso.com -Accessmethod OrgWideFB -Credential:$a
```

Source: [Configure the Availability Service for Cross-Forest Topologies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232134.aspx)

Comment: thank you for your reply. Very nice walkthrough. Also thank you for the very insightful link :)